# How to add LatLng into List<LatLng> in Android?

Tags: android

I have 2 lists.

```
double pointY[]={105.45526,105.57364,105.53505,105.45523,105.51962,105.77320}
double pointX[]={9.99222,9.88347,9.84184,9.77197,9.55501,9.67768,9}
```

I want to make a `List<LatLng>` with `LatLng[i] = (pointX[i], pointY[i])`

I have the following code but it is not working:

```
List<LatLng> points;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < pointX.length - 1; i++){
        points[i].add(LatLng(pointX[i],pointY[i]));
    };
```

How I can do it?

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: learn java ... where is a new keyword?

Comment: Not working means what happening?

Comment: It's ok, thank you very much... 
Because i'm Vietnamese , so my English is not very good.
So i have a lot of mistakes , in my question. :) Thank you every body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<LatLng> points=new ArrayList<LatLng>();
for (int i = 0 ; i < pointX.length; i++){
    points.add(new LatLng(pointX[i],pointY[i]));
};
```

Comment: This won't add the last element of the list

Comment: Hihi 

List<LatLng> points=new ArrayList<LatLng>();
for (int i = 0 ; i < pointX.length - 1; i++){
    points.add(new LatLng(pointX[i],pointY[i]));
};
Thank you so much :P

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you have seemingly failed to initialise the `points` variable - you will need to call the constructor `new ArrayList<>()`.

You are also incorrectly adding to the list within the loop and not initialising a new `LatLng` within the loop for each new point you are trying to place in the list.

The following should work:

```
List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

for (int i = 0 ; i < pointX.length; i++){
    points.add(new LatLng(pointX[i],pointY[i]));
}
```

You can then access the objects in the list as following:

```
//Some variable to determine  which point you require
int x = 0;

LatLng latlng = points.get(x);
```

Answer (score 2):

Before adding data you just initialized `ArrayList`

```
List<LatLng> points=new ArrayList<LatLng>();
```